# How can i include php script in perl application

Tags: php, perl

working in windows environment,

System configuration  Winxp, Wamp in  local disk E,

Strawberry PERL package installed in local disk c,

how to include PHP script in PERL.

What package i should install to call php script in perl.

Comment: What does the PHP script do? Can you run PHP from the command line?

Comment: PHP doing insert part,i am working in windows environment, i dont know how to run php in windows command line.

Comment: Not knowing how to run a program is a major impediment to running programs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everywhere running CLI is similar, type full path to executable binary of applpication and specify arguments separated by space.

```
system("E:/wamp/php/bin/php.exe", "d:/script/to/run.php", "argumentPasssedToPhpScript");
```

Comment: in run.php, i have three functions, but i want to use only one function in that, also i want to pass one arg or parameter to that function, my function name is insert_record_db($arg),